# Can I retrieve a managed metadata column programmatically in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've got a list with 4 managed metadata fields, I want to read the value of the field without having to do a string concatenation and having to parse out the ;#

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with the Taxonomy Hidden list like explained here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/11/18/how-to-work-with-managed-metadata-columns-by-using-the-sharepoint-client-object-model-kaushalendra-kumar.aspx and could use something like [`TaxonomyField.GetWssIdsOfKeywordTerm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625182%28v=office.14%29.aspx)